# DocuSign ClickApi endpoint

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on integrating clickApi flow in order to create userAgreements, when I read the official API docs i found there is no endpoint to create the agreements (there used to be).

if someone could provide a link or url with params it would be much appreciated.

[API Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/Accounts/ClickWraps/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry we have a gap in documentation on this.

You need to make the following call:

```
POST to /clickapi/v1/accounts/accountId/clickwraps/:clickwrapId/agreements
```

in the body put only this:

```
{
  "clientUserId": "..."
}
```

where you can use an email address for the person signing the agreement as a clientUserId or any other unique identifier.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: ok, but you asked how to create an agreement, no? I'm not clear if you're good now?

Comment: I found the correct endpoint for using the old API (POST {url_api}) but It returns 401 unauthorized as well.

I suppose it may be related to scope used in the creation of the JWT to be exchanged for the access_token. 

I tried both "signature click.manage" & "click.manage" scopes as stated in the docs https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/click101/auth.

Is this correct or are we are using the wrong scopes?